# Inserting a XML node at top

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to get the xml node to insert (insertBefore) on top instead after. For example: image1, image2, image3.

```
   <data>
   <image src="image3" />  <-- Notice 
   <image src="image2" />  <-- Notice 
   <image src="image1" />
   </data>        



    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    $dom->load('myfile.xml');

    $root = $dom->documentElement;
    $newresult = $root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('image') );

    $newresult->setAttribute('id', '10');
    $newresult->setAttribute('src', pic.jpg');
    $newresult->setAttribute('desc', 'Timothy');

    //echo ''. $dom->saveXML() .'';
    $dom->save('myfile.xml') or die('XML Manipulate Error');
```

---

Thanks! I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `appendChild()`, you want to use `insertBefore()`.

**Replace**

```
$newresult = $root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('image') );
```

**With**

```
$newresult = $root->insertBefore($dom->createElement('image'), $root->firstChild);
```

The changed code says to insert the new `image` element before the *first child* of the `data` element. This still works even if the `data` element has no child elements.

[Here's a quick demo](https://eval.in/private/590d29722dddd6).

Comment: Perfect! I was getting so close! Thank you so much!